# Displaying selected date in CalendarView in Android

Tags: android, mobile, calendarview

I have three view items. 1. Button  2. CalendarView  3. TextView
I am trying to display the selected date on TextView when i select the date AND click on the Button. Date should only appear in the TextView when the Button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
CalendarView cal = null;
TextView text = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

void Touchy(View view){
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            text.setText("");
            int d = dayOfMonth;
            int m = month;
            int y = year;
            String c = d+"-"+m+"-"+y;
            text.append(c);
        }
    });
}
```

**XML**

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:onClick="Touchy"/>
```

However the app stops when i click on the button. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: post the stacktrace. All the same the correct signature for Touchy is public void Touchy(View view). You can not change its signature to package

Comment: When initiating values at the top of a class I use CaldendarView cal; and then in the onCreate do what you did.

Comment: @blackbelt Thanks..public declarations solves this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the signature of the method you posted is wrong. It should be

```
public void Touchy(View view) {}
```